# How JDBC:inbound-channel-adapter max-row works with select for update?

Tags: oracle, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am using select for update query to avoid duplicate processing by multiple JVMs and I have `max-row=10` in `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter`.

Lets say the table has 50,000 records.

Will spring/integration/jdbc lock only 10 row or 50000?

also, as per documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/html/jdbc.html

> "It is recommended to use result set limiting via vendor-specific query options, for example MySQL LIMIT or SQL Server TOP or Oracle’s ROWNUM. See the particular vendor documentation for more information."

That means server would pick all the records fetched by query.

```xml
    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="initial.poller"
        query="select id from transaction where status='created'"
        max-rows="10"
        update="update transaction set status='processed' where ID in (:id)"
        row-mapper="pollerRowMapper"
        data-source="dataSource" channel="transactionChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="200" time-unit="MILLISECONDS">
            <int:transactional  />
        </int:poller>

    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I checked in debug mode only 10 rows are getting locked by a jvm and other JVMS are picking up and processing the other records.

1) How is spring/hibernate is communicating to oracle to lock only the 10 records that it are being picking?

2) What is the purpose of `max-rows`, if ROWNUM has to be used in the query?

Edit 1: There is no way to us select for update and rownum together. None of these are allowed on oracle:

```
select * from (select id from transaction where status='created' order by id) WHERE rownum <= 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED ;
select * from (select id from transaction where status='created' order by id FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) WHERE rownum <= 10  ;
```

How can I get the performance optimization? table has millions or records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The maximum number of rows to query. Default is zero - select all records.
 * @param maxRows the max rows to set
 * @since 5.1
 */
public void setMaxRows(int maxRows) {
```

So, we may make an assumption that this will really limit records somehow. And this is how it is done in the code:

```
return new PreparedStatementCreatorWithMaxRows(preparedStatementCreator,
                    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.this.maxRows);

...
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.delegate.createPreparedStatement(con);
        preparedStatement.setMaxRows(this.maxRows); // We can't mutate provided JdbOperations for this option
        return preparedStatement;
    }
```

And let's take a look into those JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any
 * <code>ResultSet</code> object  generated by this <code>Statement</code>
 * object can contain to the given number.
 * If the limit is exceeded, the excess
 * rows are silently dropped.
 *
 * @param max the new max rows limit; zero means there is no limit
 * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs,
 * this method is called on a closed <code>Statement</code>
 *            or the condition {@code max >= 0} is not satisfied
 * @see #getMaxRows
 */
void setMaxRows(int max) throws SQLException;
```

So, that's the place where it is limited. I think you are safe with what you have so far even if that `ROWNUM` doesn't work together with the `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: ok, so max-rows drop the excess records silently and the record locking works somehow but, unfortunately, max-rows option is not suitable for last dataset. My poller is set to 200ms but query fetch takes 30mins without ROWNUM.

Comment: yeah, I was relying max-rows though. I will add oracle tag here but I know the only option with oracle is to go with store proc and inbound-channel-adapter won't be able to run a store proc instead of a query...so I am stuck

Comment: How you can be stuck if there is a Stored Proc support in Spring integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures ?

Comment: Thanks, just realized that, store proc is supported but select for update in the store proc would be a different transaction then the Spring container.

Comment: You can start transaction from the poller, so it will be propagated into database